# Do a Find in Current Namespace in Visual Studio?

Tags: search, visual-studio-2012

Want to be able to do a Find but contain my results to the current namespace the current opened file is in. Like "Current Project" but "Current Namespace". Is there a plugin or tool that can do this?

Comment: Why not current file?  If your namespace spans multiple files, just run it on all the files (I mean, how many files does it take to define a namespace?) or to find in current selection and highlight your namespace if it's just a subset of the file contents.

Comment: we have multiple folders in a namespace I would like to find across all files in all sub-folders in the current namespace

Comment: Hrmm, in short, I don't know, but with more description of the layout, maybe a crafty solution can be found (for instance: can you search all files for namespace::identifer, and then only search a couple files for identifier?)

Comment: I don't know of a buit-in command to do this, but if 3rd party tools are an option, I would recommand Resharper.  The Go To Symbol, and the new Go To Everything command (bound to ctrl+T) is extremely effective.

Comment: Too sad macros was removed in this version of Visual Studio otherwise you can create a fancy macro for your request

Comment: Why is this off topic?

Comment: @nawfal: who says that it's off-topic?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I wasn't talking about the strict SO definition of "off topic", but about its general meaning, that a question considered closeworthy, ie, not fit for SO.

Comment: @nawfal: are we talking about the same question? This one has 6 upvotes.

Comment: @JohnSaunders and what has upvote got to do with the question being closed? The question was closed, I voted it to be re-opened. Now where did I go wrong? I'm not getting you, I think.

Comment: @nawfal: if the question was ever closed, then I don't know about it. It's open now, so what's your question?

Comment: Yup, the question was closed, and my comment was before it being re-opened. Hope its clear now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use a regex :

```
namespace my_namespace(.*\n)*.*my_search
```

That's kind of an ugly solution, since it will select everything between namespace keyword and you search. But that's still useful. 
You can adapt it and change capture groups in order to be able to use it for replacements.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than parsing and inspecting every code file individually, Agent Mulder plugin utilizes ReSharper's Structural Search (sometimes known as Structural Search and Replace, or SSR) to look for patterns of code in the entire solution. This is both effective (since the solution structure already exists in ReSharper's caches), and makes it very easy to extend Agent Mulder to support additional containers.

[Here is an overview](https://github.com/hmemcpy/AgentMulder/wiki/ReSharper%27s-Structural-Search) of ReSharper's Structural Search API (based on ReSharper SDK v6.1)